# .htaccess Rewrite redirecting URLs

Tags: .htaccess

In my .htaccess file, I've got the fairly standard

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC]
```

and I only need this to happen to files in my root directory.  However, if I go to the URL of one of my subdirectories (with or without a index.php file), such as `www.foo.com/bar`, then I am redirected to `www.foo.com/bar/?p=bar` - how do I prevent the addition of `?p=bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making the rule only execute for non directories as below

```
#if it is not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#then send it to index.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `.htaccess` files into the sub-directories.

```
# /bar/.htaccess

AllowOverride none
```

This should prevent the `.htaccess` inheritance.

Comment: I am not sure, if this is the best approach; he'd have to update all subdirectories ad infinitum to excape his overeager rewrite rule on root level.

Comment: Well, yes.  Another option is to add checks for each sub-directory in a `RewriteCond`, but that, also, would have to be maintained for every new directory.  But to your point, that is probably more reasonable...